# Android - How do you make a button on a screen overlay clickable

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement a simple lockscreen through screen overlay. I added a button to the XML layout, the app successfully covered the screen but the button doesn't seem to work.

```
    public WindowManager winManager;
    public RelativeLayout wrapperView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState). {      ((KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE)).newKeyguardLock("IN").disableKeyguard();
    PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
            p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(),     PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
        finish();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams     localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams( WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|

                                                                                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL|
                                                                                      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
                                                                                      PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        this.winManager =     ((WindowManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE));
        this.wrapperView = new     RelativeLayout(getBaseContext());
        getWindow().setAttributes(localLayoutParams);
        View.inflate(this, R.layout.lackiscreen, this.wrapperView);
        this.winManager.addView(this.wrapperView, localLayoutParams);


    }
    public void dclick(View view){
        this.winManager.removeView(this.wrapperView);
        this.wrapperView.removeAllViews();
    }
```

Comment: Is the method supposed to be called `dclick`? Or is the 'd' a typo?

Comment: you can use Dialog with setCancelable(false) property to lock Screen

Comment: It is not a typo, "dclick" is the onClick of the button. I often use it instead of a click listener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android only allows very specific windows to receive touch events when they are an overlay. You need to get your flags right.

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
);
```

Hope that helps. (Works for me at least)

Comment: Thanks it actually worked like charm! But I didn't need to do the onClick listener the void worked the same.

Comment: I didn't know how and if you called the dclick method so I included it. Simplified my answer now. Happy to help.