# Two button views added to WindowManager but only one of them is clickable

Tags: android, android-button, android-windowmanager

I am building an app where I am using a WindowManager to overlay a menu on top of whatever the user was doing prior. I have two buttons added as views to the WindowManager and have selected their sizes using LayoutParams. However, only the last button added to the WindowManager is clickable but I am not sure why this is happening. Does anyone know how I can reduce the clickable area of the second button so that the first is also clickable?

It seems as though the entire screen is clickable for Button B but no where is clickable for Button A.

For further context, this WindowManager is part of an ASyncTask, which runs every 500ms.

```
buttonA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonA);
buttonA.setBackgroundColor(0xBB000000);
((ViewGroup)buttonA.getParent()).removeView(buttonA);
buttonB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonB);
buttonB.setBackgroundColor(0xBB000000);
((ViewGroup)buttonB.getParent()).removeView(buttonB);
windowManager3 = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
windowManager3.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
params3 = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
params3.width = 800;
params3.height = 500;
params3.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
params3.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
 params3.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
}
else {
 params3.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
}

params3.y = 0;
params3.height = 200;
windowManager3.addView(coopUI, params3);
params3.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.LEFT;
params3.y = 200;
params3.height = 150;
params3.width = 400;
params3.x = 130;
windowManager3.addView(buttonA, params3);
params3.x = 550;
windowManager3.addView(buttonB, params3);
```

```xml
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonB"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Takeover"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="459dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonA"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Yes"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="459dp" />
```

Comment: try to provide all related code for your problem, like definition of your windowManager2 and buttonA and buttonB and etc...

Comment: thanks Rasool, I've updated with more code and explanation.

Comment: try giving width and height as wrap_content to your buttons

Comment: @AsadAli just tried that and it doesn't seem to make a difference. It seems that the entire screen is a clickable area for Button B for some reason.

Comment: It looks like the problem was fixed by adding very specific flags from this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53043643/android-how-do-you-make-a-button-on-a-screen-overlay-clickable